# Why this batch script not work fine?

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

What's wrong with this script?

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /P start= Input start : %=%
set /P end= Input End : %=%

for /l %%i IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO (
    set num=0%%i
    set num=!num:~-2!
    echo wget "http://portal/excel!num!.xls"
)
pause
```

if `Input start = 01`, `Input End = 06`, work fine and excel files downloaded. Result :

```
Input start : 01
Input End : 12
wget "http://portal/excel01.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel02.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel03.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel04.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel05.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel06.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel07.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel08.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel09.xls"
wget "http://portal/excel10.xls"
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But if `Input start = 01`, `Input End = 08` OR 
if `Input start = 01`, `Input End = 09`, Not work fine and excel files not downloaded. Result :

```
Input start : 01
Input End : 08
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Can anyone give some explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leading zero means number is intepreted as octal.  0-7 don't matter, but there is no such number as an octal 8 or 9. You are already adding a leading 0 with the 2 SET commands, so don't enter the leading zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is a workaround:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION    
set start=101
set end=199

for /l %%i IN (%start%,1,%end%) DO (
     set num=!num:~-2!
    echo wget "http://portal/excel!num!.xls"
)
```